# How should I pack h264 to PES

Tags: h.264, mpeg2-ts

Please tell me the best case to packing SPS PPS into PES package.

I have raw h264 stream like:

```
SPS PPS IDR P P ... P SPS PPS IDR P...
```

How should I packing it into PES? I packing like:

```
[PES with PTS] SPS PPS IDR [PES with PTS] P [PES with PTS] ...
```

or I should

```
[PES with PTS] SPS [PES with PTS] PPS [PES with PTS] ... ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One PES packet per access Unit. Access Unit delimiters are required for TS.

Comment: Yes, I put access unit in NAL. My stream looks like
    [PES header] [NAL header] [Access unit delimiter] [SPS] [PPS] [IDR] [PES header] [NAL header] [Access unit delimiter] [P] ...